# What type of Salesforce account do we need?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

I've read through the documentation and I am under the impression that I should do all of my work with a developer account, but since this is a very important issue for my company, I wanted to ask here to be absolutely sure.

My company does not use Salesforce to manage our sales pipeline. However, our customers do use Salesforce. We sell data that helps our customers identify new leads.

I've been put in charge of developing our integration with Salesforce (this will allow our customers to automate the import of data, which is currently handled in a manual manner).

When I started this work, a month ago, I signed up for an enterprise account. This gave me what I needed: the account had the API enabled, and the ability for me to build custom Apex and VisualForce pages. But it came with a 30 day limit. And that is about to expire.

From what I've read, my company only needs for me to have a developer account? Is it true that a developer account is free, forever? We don't ever need to pay? There is no 30 day limit?

When I'm done with my work, we will release our Salesforce app on the Salesforce App Exchange, as a managed app.

Since we don't use Salesforce to manage our sales, but we are selling to companies that use Salesforce, I need an account that allows me to develop custom code and release it as a managed app in the Salesforce app exchange.

What kind of Salesforce account should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A developer account in salesforce is used for development of managed package applications as they do not expire if you login frequently .

Developer accounts have all the sales and service cloud features for you to test against and also has API access to build and test .

If you are building an appexchange application ,you may want to sign up for a partner program as an ISV which would provide access to a partner developer orgs which has more data limits compared to a DE org .

Here is a complete Trailhead module that talks about how you should proceed

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/isv_app_development

Comment: Do we need to pay for a developer account? Is there a 30 day trial, or are they free forever?

Comment: Free for ever .You do not need to pay anything .You can sign up for partner program and you will get a partner org where you can either request environment hub or use a free sign up for DE org ..https://developer.salesforce.com/signup